# Error converting Tensorflow Object Detection Api model to TFLite

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I trained a SSDLite-MobilenetV2 model with Tensorflow using the [provided documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) in the Object Detection Api. Then I exported the model by running the [export_tflite_ssd_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py) script. A pb and a pbtxt file were generated. Finally, I tried to convert the model to tflite format using the tflite_convert command. However, I got the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/tflite_convert", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 412, in main
app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 408, in run_main
_convert_model(tflite_flags)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 100, in _convert_model
converter = _get_toco_converter(flags)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 87, in _get_toco_converter
return converter_fn(**converter_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py", line 340, in from_saved_model
output_arrays, tag_set, signature_key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert_saved_model.py", line 239, in freeze_saved_model
meta_graph = get_meta_graph_def(saved_model_dir, tag_set)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert_saved_model.py", line 61, in get_meta_graph_def
return loader.load(sess, tag_set, saved_model_dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 197, in load
return loader.load(sess, tags, import_scope, **saver_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 350, in load
** saver_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 275, in load_graph
meta_graph_def = self.get_meta_graph_def_from_tags(tags)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 251, in get_meta_graph_def_from_tags
" could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in"
RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags set(['serve']) could not be found in SavedModel. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: saved_model_cli**

It seems that the conversion script did not include the SERVING tag constant. How can I fix this?

I am using tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0

Comment: you need to install tensorflow from source to do this. You probably have installed tensorflow binary

Comment: So is it a bug in the binary?

Comment: To convert frozen graph to tflite you must have installed tensor flow from source.